# JButtons re-enable themselves after disabled and other enabled JButtons not truly enabled

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

The issue I am currently facing is that I have a JFrame with about 6561 buttons and I want to enable only 9 of them depending on which JButton was clicked. I am usually able to do this, but after a certain change where I recreate the JFrame, it stops working. I do not know why this is the case.

```
if(abwincheck[m/r][h/r] == null) {
    if(cdwincheck[m/3][h/3] == null) {
        if(bcwincheck[m][h] == null) {
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<3; j++) {
                    if(bcwincheck[i][j] == null) {
                        for(int k=0; k<9; k++) {
                            if(n == 2)
                                newDossier.Board.metaboard[i][j].getComponent(k).setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                    if(n == 3) {
                        if(abwincheck[i][j]  ==  null) {
                            for(int b=0; b<l; b++) {
                                for (int c=0; c<l; c++) {
                                    if(bcwincheck[b][c] == null) {
                                        for(int k=0; k<9; k++) {
                                            for(int a=0; a<9; a++) {
                                                Component []componentsx3 = newDossier.Board.metametaboard[i][j].getComponents();
                                                if(componentsx3.length>1) {
                                                    Component []components = ((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametaboard[i][j].getComponent(k)).getComponents();
                                                    if(components.length>1)
                                                        ((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametaboard[i][j].getComponent(k)).getComponent(a).setEnabled(false);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(n == 4) {
                        if(abwincheck[i][j]  ==  null) {
                            for (int b=0; b<9; b++) {
                                for(int c=0; c<9; c++) {
                                    if(cdwincheck[b][c] == null) {
                                        if(bcwincheck[i*9+b][j*9+c] == null) {
                                            for(int k=0; k<9; k++) {
                                                for(int a=0; a<9; a++) {
                                                    for(int p=0; p<9; p++) {
                                                        Component []componentsx3 = newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[i][j].getComponents();
                                                        if(componentsx3.length>1) {
                                                            Component []componentsx9 = ((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[i][j].getComponent(k)).getComponents();
                                                            if(componentsx9.length>1) {
                                                                Component []components = ((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[i][j].getComponent(k)).getComponent(a)).getComponents();
                                                                if(components.length>1) {
                                                                    ((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[i][j].getComponent(k)).getComponent(a)).getComponent(p).setEnabled(false);
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<l; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<l; j++) {
                    if(i == m && j == h) {
                        for(int k=0; k<9; k++) {
                            if(n == 2 && ((JButton)newDossier.Board.metaboard[i][j].getComponent(k)).getText().equals("")) {
                                newDossier.Board.metaboard[i][j].getComponent(k).setEnabled(true);
                            }
                            if(n == 3 && ((JButton)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametaboard[i/3][j/3].getComponent((m%3)*3+h%3)).getComponent(k)).getText().equals("")) {
                                ((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametaboard[i/3][j/3].getComponent((m%3)*3+h%3)).getComponent(k).setEnabled(true);
                            }
                            if(n == 4 && ((JButton)((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[i/9][j/9].getComponent(((m%9)/3)*3+(h%9)/3)).getComponent(((m%9)%3)*3+(h%9)%3)).getComponent(k)).getText().equals("")) {
                                ((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[i/9][j/9].getComponent(((m%9)/3)*3+(h%9)/3)).getComponent(((m%9)%3)*3+(h%9)%3)).getComponent(k).setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if(n == 3||(n == 2 && bcwincheck[i][j] == null)) {
                            for(int k=0; k<9; k++) {
                                if(n == 2)
                                    newDossier.Board.metaboard[i][j].getComponent(k).setEnabled(false);
                                if(n == 4||(n == 3 && bcwincheck[i][j] == null)) {
                                    for(int a=0; a<9; a++) {
                                        if(i<3 && j<3) {
                                            Component [] componentsx3 = newDossier.Board.metametaboard[i][j].getComponents();
                                            if(componentsx3.length>1) {
                                                Component [] components = ((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametaboard[i][j].getComponent(k)).getComponents();
                                                if(components.length>1)
                                                    ((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametaboard[i][j].getComponent(k)).getComponent(a).setEnabled(false);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if(n == 4 && bcwincheck[i][j] == null) {
                                            for(int p=0; p<9; p++) {
                                                if(i<3 && j<3) {
                                                    Component [] componentsx3 = newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[i][j].getComponents();
                                                    if(componentsx3.length>1) {
                                                        Component [] componentsx9 = ((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[i][j].getComponent(k)).getComponents();
                                                        if(componentsx9.length>1) {
                                                            Component[] components = ((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametametaboard[i][j].getComponent(k)).getComponent(a)).getComponents();
                                                            if(components.length>1)
                                                                ((JPanel)((JPanel)newDossier.Board.metametaboard[i][j].getComponent(k)).getComponent(a)).getComponent(p).setEnabled(false);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

There is more code pertaining to all the changes, but this is the part you need to see.

The change that results in the failure is the fact that one of the panels in metametametaboard[0][0] has all buttons removed and only a JLabel instead. The JButtons enable and disable correctly any other time the JFrame is recreated... but with this change it stops working for whatever reason. Please advise.

Comment: 6 THOUSAND JButtons? Might I suggest rethinking your design?

Comment: Ahhhh, my eyes, my eyes....that's a bunch of conditions that have no context or meaning. Best bet is to either add some break points and debug the code or add some system outs

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Note: when you have lines that long, and nesting that deep, it's time to refactor your code. Six months from now, you'll find this impossible to maintain.

Comment: It sounds like it's getting pretty hard to maintain already...